# LdrQueryImageFileExecutionOptions usefulness

Tags: api, loader

i'm asking about the loader function LdrQueryImageFileExecutionOptions, it is not documented. my questions are :
1- Why this API is called only by some program and not by others?
2- if it is not called, what is the impact?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in a security context benignware can use this API to enable debugger mode. then to answer my questions:
1- Why is this API only called by some programs and not by others?
is to enable debug mode. it can also be used to associate a program with a default opener of a file type [[1]](https://blog.malwarebytes.com/101/2015/12/an-introduction-to-image-file-execution-options/).
2- if it is not called, what is the impact? we know that debug mode will be disabled and there were not a modification in default applications. this information can be used in malware analysis.